# How to automatically reboot my server every 4 hours?

Tags: command-line, server, reboot

I need help with my dedicated Ubuntu server.
How can I reboot my server every 4 hours?

Comment: Have you thought about cron?  Something like `0 */4 * * * sudo reboot`?

Comment: Im just new with ubuntu. but i know about crontab

Comment: Why do you need your server rebooted? As ThatGuy mentioned, cron may be a good place to start. But in general Unix and Unix-like machines should be capable of running for days (or even weeks or months!) without needing restarted. It sounds like there may be another issue that needs addressing.

Comment: Because i'm runnning 8 minecraft servers in my dedicated server.

Comment: @JohnN has a point.  Even with Minecraft servers, they should not require that the server be rebooted that frequently, unless you've misconfigured the game servers, or use mods with severe memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

***The `crontab` Method***

- Open your Terminal or SSH into your server
- Type `sudo crontab -e` and the press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Use the down arrow key to go to the bottom of the text
- Type `0 */4 * * * sudo reboot`
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Press <kbd>Y</kbd>
- Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If all went well, it should reboot every 4 hours, on the hour.

Comment: But would it automatically log in to the user account?

Comment: What user account?  It would reboot the server using the root account, which should override every other user, regardless who is logged in.

Comment: @ThatGuy I think Giridhur is asking if after restart the log-in will be automatic.

Comment: @tomas - I see. If it is using Ubuntu Server, then definitely not. It would be a potential security problem, no administrator wants their server to auto login. If it's Ubuntu Desktop, then it depends on how he configured it.

Comment: @ThatGuy I think you should address your reply @ Giridhur.